# Use both libnative and libgreen in a Rust program

Tags: rust

I'm currently designing a process where I have to spawn *a lot* of tasks. It's a conception choice I've made because I understood that it was possible in Rust. However, affirmations saying that Rust can spawned “hundreds of thousands of tasks” have disappeared since 1:1 model adoption by default.

My question is simple: is it possible to spawn green tasks for non-IO, light tasks and native tasks for IO operation ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can probably use `libgreen`, but `libgreen`'s "green threads" were never much more cheaper (in memory per thread or in time to spawn) than OS threads to begin with, which is why the "hundreds of thousands of tasks" claim disappeared (it was wrong) and why libgreen is being phased out.

Comment: That's what I understood from my last content. Now, my other question: is it possible to have tasks with very little tasks (few kB, against 64 by default and claimed as minimum) ? In order to avoid stack overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `green` crate still exists, if you want to spawn "green threads" through libuv.  But you probably don't want to.

The problem boils down to how Rust handles the stack, and how it detects overflow.  Originally, Rust used split stacks, which meant that it could allocate very small stacks and, thus, each green thread used very little memory.  Overflow was detected by an explicit check.

The problem is that this turns out to be really inefficient.  Worse, it made even native threads slower, since the code couldn't know which one it was going to run on.  As a result, Rust ditched split stacks for guard pages.  That is, there's always an extra, empty 4K page below a thread's stack that catches invalid accesses.

However, that's how native thread stacks work.  So when the change went through, green threads were suddenly as memory inefficient as regular threads, and were saddling Rust with a big runtime component.

Hence why `green` is being excised and turned into a regular, external library.  You can still use it, but it's not really as clear when you'd want to use it now.

As a point of comparison, Go has recently or will soon make the same change.

As for "hundreds of thousands of tasks", the argument now is that if you want to do that, run in a 64-bit environment, where lazy memory mapping will make the problem disappear.  Hopefully.

**Edit**: as an addendum, if Rust *does* get very memory-cheap "tasks" in the future, I'd personally be looking at Python 3-style generators.  Rust doesn't have a nice way to do them, but that's where I'd be putting my money...

Comment: So basically, the answer is “no, you cannot have both green and native tasks in the same process”?

Comment: Oh, no, you can.  The `green` crate is now just another crate like any other library.  You can't switch a Rust program *globally* to use green threads; you need to explicitly spawn them.  I can't really say more than that because, again, this is a transition-in-progress, and I've never tried to use it directly.  But again, I'm not sure there's any *benefit* to doing so, since they don't take up less memory, and aren't faster, insofar as I'm aware.

Comment: Actually it is possible to use globally `green` by overwritting _start function. I need to do some tests, but for what I saw, they *do* less memory in heap (but not less memory in stack). But maybe I'm wrong!

Answer (score 3):

The memory consumption of `libgreen` *might* be slightly lower but actually you can easily specify the size of the stack for any task using [`TaskBuilder`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/task/struct.TaskBuilder.html):

```
extern crate native;

use std::task::TaskBuilder;
use native::NativeTaskBuilder;

TaskBuilder::new().stack_size(21*1024).spawn(proc() {
    timer::sleep(20000)
});
```

Note that [in July](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2014-July/010715.html) Alex Crichton noted that a *red zone* of 20kB was reserved for calls into C. Therefore, if you specify 21kB you only get 1kB that you can use *yourself* as you are not allowed to get into the *red zone*. It's making the interface a little... special.

Add to that the 4kB guard page, and it means that there is an overhead of at 24kB for which you hope that laziness will help. You will need a 64bits address space, for sure.

---

Where I would hope `libgreen` to shine, however, is in scheduling. The OS might not be able to manipulate dozens of thousands of threads as efficiently as `libgreen`. However, it is something that you will need to test for yourself in your particular setup.

Given that even in libgreen yield points are explicit though, it might be easier for you to use *stackless coroutines*. That is:

- define a `Coroutine` object with some state
- define a channel of `Coroutine` (maybe based on `sync::mpmc_bounded_queue`)
- pop a `Coroutine` from the channel, execute the next step, push it back in the channel

While more "hand-craft", if it fits your model it will result in a *great* memory consumption reduction as those `Coroutine` objects are very lightweight and only a handful of threads may be sufficient to handle their execution.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. Do you have any example in mind I would be able to look at?

Comment: @ThomasLetan: this is the model used in event loops, in short. If you push the `Coroutine` on Rust's Channel, it gets really easy. Rust does not have Multi-Consumers channels though, so if you need multiple threads of execution then you can maybe leverage `mpmc_bound_queue` however my understanding is that it does not implement blocking pop: if there is nothing the consumer gets a `None` and has to implement some exponential sleep-off strategy if it wants to avoid burning CPU... which kinda kills latency. You could probably implement a mutex-based MPMC queue yourself.